# Directory folder to store document

Tags: node.js, reactjs, mongodb

I am trying to make document management project  using nodejs,mongodb and react. I want to make directory folder that will store document and the sub is it file. But I could not find any reference that I could use to start making the directory. Is there any specific term that I should search to get any reference to start the project? Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Multer library for file uploads. It's super easy to use.

```
import multer from 'multer';

//specify where you want your files to be stored
var fileStorageEngine = multer.diskStorage({
    destination: function (req, file, cb) {
        cb(null, './images')
    },
    filename: function (req, file, cb) {
        cb(null, Date.now() + '--' + file.originalname)
    }
})
var upload = multer({ storage: fileStorageEngine });

//pass it as a middleware to a route where you expect to get a file upload
app.use('/api/file/', upload.single('image'), someRouterHere);
```

Comment: Hi can it also make it in directory that list our upload document?

Comment: Yes you can specify where you want the files to be stored. It can be inside any directory you want. Check the documentation at https://www.npmjs.com/package/multer to get started.

Comment: so i can make it function like file explorer using multer? Sorry for asking..i am new to multer..

Comment: You can add files to a directory with multer if that's what you are asking about. You can also use fs module in Node to read files from your directories.